# Dictionary or List of delegates for a test, with unknown value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, delegates

I'm looking for something that I'm sure that has been asked before, but I don't know what to look for.

I want to create list/dictionary of functions that must be passed. Then, I can pass a string value through all these checks/functions/delegates. Something very much like this :

```
var test = "12345";

var thing = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
thing.Add("key", new Action( t => IsNumeric.Test(t)));
thing.Add("key", new Action(t => Length.Test(t, 5)));
```

Where Length and Isnumeric will be examples of my tests. My problem is, at this stage I dont know what the value will be that I'm passing to the function.

Any advice?

Comment: Will the methods have different signatures?

Comment: you are thinking of `new Dictionary<string, Predicate<TValue>>`?

Comment: There is no attempt to do anything with the test results. And in the end the answer will be: use a test framework, like xUnit.

Comment: @Mike, no. In this case, I have IsNumeric.Test(string), and Length(Test(string, int),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me :

```
return new List<Predicate<string>>()
{
    (x => Validate.Length(x, 2, 22, messageStack)),
    (x => Validate.PlainText(x, messageStack))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized my own answer the moment I posted the question.

```
var test = "12345";

var thing = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
thing.Add("key", new Action( () => IsNumeric.Test(test)));
thing.Add("key", new Action( () => Length.Test(test, 5)));
```

Just pass the value to the delegate (obviously).

Comment: Not so obvious, `test` is a capture and this whole thing is not reusable in any way.